# WebPartManager issue in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am using ASP.Net + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + IIS 7.0 + C# to develop a web application. I am using WebPartManager, and I find when personalization feature is enabled to true, the web application will connect to SQL Server Express version database automatically.

BTW: I find this by when stop SQL Server Express version service instance, there will be database connection error shown.

My question is, (1) why WebPartManager needs to connect to SQL Server Express version when personalization feature is enabled (in other words, SQL Server Express version is used by personalization feature for what purpose)? (2) If I need personalization feature, any solutions to change to SQL Server Enterprise other than SQL Server Express version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in a .mdf file in your /Data folder.

You can change to a SQL Server store using the web adminstration tool or SQL Server set up wizard.

If you need to use another source other than SQL Server, you need to write your own Provider to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I think you mean by default -- "data is stored in a .mdf file in your /Data folder"? I am interested in this point, do you have any recommended readings for this point? Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163965.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300767.aspx#S8 

Google? :)